# How does the ampersand in most fonts resemble "et"

Tags: ampersand

I [read](https://medium.com/black-lion-banner/the-history-of-the-ampersand-c81839171940) that the ampersand `&` started off as a ligature for "et" ("and" in Latin). An example of an ampersand that does look like "et" can be seen in this very site's logo. So how does the shape of `&` in the majority of fonts resemble this at all? If it doesn't, then why was this shape chosen?

I know there will be fonts with different looks, but the majority of fonts look like this and those are what I'm asking about.

Comment: Consider what "et" looks like in handwritten script.

Comment: @HotLicks I see no similarity whatsoever.

Comment: By "script" I mean "longhand" or "cursive'.

Comment: See the illustrations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand

Comment: It changed little by little over time so that now it doesn't look anything like the original.

Comment: Look at the top of the page. As it happens, the EL&U logotype features a particularly E + T -like ampersand.

Comment: @tmgr I know, but i'm asking about one that looks like `&`

Comment: @FireCubez The point is, it's a continuum: I'm sure you can see the resemblance between the ampersand at the top of the page and a more standard &-looking one, and you can see how the one at the top of the page looks like an E and a T. Here's the ampersand variants from one (modern) script font from a reputable foundry: https://www.fonthaus.com/fonts/monotypeimaging/poetica/MI35611638 Some are more &, some are more E + T... hopefully that'll show the links. If not, try looking at samples of copperplate script to show how the pen can flow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This intrigued me so I thought I'd play around with it.

I got the following:

[image]

I don't claim it's right but it wasn't too hard to come up with some continuity.

EDIT - I should have mentioned that versions 2 and 5 came directly from the Wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand - All the others were derived from playing around.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you posted this as a separate answer, rather than incorporating both into one answer? I don’t think this continuity is quite how the & shape was historically arrived at (I think 3 and 4 developed a bit differently), but it’s not particularly far off either.

Comment: I suppose my first answer relied on quoted sources. This one is purely speculative. I didn't want to imply I was claiming validity for this by juxtaposing it with the others.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of Googling yields the following:

> Design History: Get to know your ampersands, by Kaitlyn Ellison
>
> It was once the 27th letter of the alphabet, derived from the Roman
> word for and: ‘et’. When ancient Roman scribes were scribbling away in
> Roman Cursive around the 1st century AD, they had a tendency to
> connect to two letters into a ligature.
>
> That symbol evolved over time, and by the Renaissance had developed
> into the calligraphic symbol that we’re so familiar with now.
>
> https://99designs.co.uk/blog/tips/history-of-ampersands-typography/

---

Wikipedia adds the information that the origin was not from 'et' but 'Et'.

> Symbols originating as ligatures
>
> The most common ligature is the
> ampersand &. This was originally a ligature of E and t, forming the
> Latin word "et", meaning "and". It has exactly the same use in French
> and in English. The ampersand comes in many different forms. Because
> of its ubiquity, it is generally no longer considered a ligature, but
> a logogram.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

Comment: Still can't see how `&` looks like 'Et'. Am I just missing it?